# Remove a specific element of a TimeSeries?

Tags: time-series, peak-detection

If I have a TimeSeries, how do I remove an element if that element is another TimeSeries? Let's say I have:

`ts2 = TimeSeries[{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, {1}];`

and I want to remove the fifth (5) element. To find the peak, I can do:

`FindPeaks[ts2]` and that results in another TimeSeries. How to I use this information to remove element 5 so I have a TimeSeries that eliminates that peak? Resultant TimeSeries should be n-1 elements long, where n is the starting number of elements in the series.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this apart from extracting the values from the `TimeSeries`, removing the peak and reconstructing the `TimeSeries`. Inefficient for large `TimeSeries`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`TimeSeriesResample`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesResample.html) as follows:

```
ts2 = TimeSeries[{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, {1}];
pks = FindPeaks[ts2];
ts3 = TimeSeriesResample[ts2, { Complement[ts2["Times"], pks["Times"]]}]

Normal@ts3
```

> `{{1, 0.}, {2, 0.}, {3, 0.}, {4, 0.}, {6, 0.}, {7, 0.}, {8, 0.}}`

Answer (score 4):

### Complete automation

I think what you are actually looking for is `DeleteAnomalies`. Define these data:

```
ts=TimeSeries[{1,2,3,15,3,2,1},{1}]
```

Now compare old and new:

```
DateListPlot[
    {ts,TimeSeries[DeleteAnomalies[ts["Path"]]]},
PlotMarkers->Automatic,PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

### Surgery

Now if you want to play surgeon, you can define a function:

```
deleteTS[ts_,pts_]:=
DeleteMissing[TimeSeriesInsert[ts,TimeSeries[Thread[{pts,Missing[]}]]]]
```

It uses `TimeSeriesInsert` to replace elements at positions pts with `Missing[]` and then removes them with `DeleteMissing`. For example compare:

```
ts["Path"]
deleteTS[ts, {4}]["Path"]
deleteTS[ts, FindPeaks[ts]["Times"]]["Path"]

Out[1]= {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 15}, {5, 3}, {6, 2}, {7, 1}}
Out[2]= {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {5, 3}, {6, 2}, {7, 1}}
Out[3]= {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {5, 3}, {6, 2}, {7, 1}}
```

You can also delete a set of points:

```
DateListPlot[
    {ts,deleteTS[ts,{3,5}]},
PlotMarkers->Automatic,PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

and add some fancy replacement/smothing for deleted points:

```
DateListPlot[
    {ts,
    TimeSeriesResample[deleteTS[ts,{4}],
    ResamplingMethod->{"Interpolation",InterpolationOrder->2}]},
PlotMarkers->Automatic,PlotRange->All]
```

[image]